# How to hard reset MI tablet when the volume down key and power key combination leads to fastboot screen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tablet, hard-reset

I want to hard reset my MI tablet as I have forgotten the pattern and the developer options are also not turned on. By try all the key combinations, the fastboot screen comes up and the boot menu doesn't show up. Is there any way through which I could hard reset my tablet?

Comment: Is volume up + power button loads Mi Recovery?

Comment: No it doesn't. I have tried all the key combinations, either it loads the fastboot mode or the normal boot continues.

Comment: Is the device Xiaomi? Do you have unlocked the bootloader?

Comment: Yes the device is of Xiaomi. How do I unlock the bootloader ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wipe the userdata partition  in Fastboot mode.

Connect the device to an USB cable. Install drivers if needed, you'll have to download them.

Download [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](https://androidmtk.com/download-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-tool) ([link 2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)), it a command-line utility. Open it and tape, the following:

`fastboot -w` (confirm by hitting ENTER)

The device shall reboot and all settings reset.

Comment: where and how should I use this command ?

Comment: check my edited answer.